# which graphics card drivers should you install if you have two Nvidia graphics cards?

Tags: windows, windows-8, drivers, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card

I have two graphics cards installed in one PC - an NVIDIA 7300 LE and NVIDIA 8400GS.  The computer is not used for gaming, but they are used for a triple-monitor setup.

I've went on the Nvidia site and downloaded the latest drivers for both.  If I install the latest for the 7300LE, it works fine.   If I install the latest for the 8400GS, the 7300LE stops working.

If I use the native Windows drivers, they work fine.  If I install the latest for the 7300LE, it will then automatically upgrade itself by time to the latest one for 8400GS, and the 7300LE stop working.

Which ones should I keep?  I'm currently using the drivers Windows 8 has natively, and everything seems to be working fine.  Should I bother with Nvidia's?

Comment: I remember Nvidia stopped supporting the 7,8,9 series quite a while ago (they're passing to Legacy). Use the 7300LE driver and disable the automatic update, that's my suggestion.

Comment: Currently I'm using the Windows 8 drivers as it's working fine, just wanted to know what is the 'best' option in terms of reliability / performance. With the 7300LE, and with the Windows 8 drivers, I didnt' experience anything different.  It's just the 8400GS one that was making the 7300LE not working.

Comment: Like I said, I believe Nvidia stopped supporting those old models. Unless you use unofficial drivers, *with Windows 8*, you aren't getting much better. I would recommend you to wait for more answers/comments.

Answer (score 0):

You should ideally use the same driver for both the cards to ensure stability. In your scenario, since the updated drivers cause problems you are best off with the windows driver or as has been rightly suggested by Doctoro Reichard use the official Nvidia 7300LE driver with automatic updates disabled